# Rails 3 scoped finds giving ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am upgrading a Rails application from 2.3.10 to 3.0.4 and am running into an issue with updating models in my controller. I have been "scoping" model finds in order to prevent users from updating objects that don't belong to them. It works as expected in 2.3, but I get an ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord error with update_attributes in Rails 3.

What is the right way to do this in Rails 3?

Project controller:

```
def update
  @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])

  if @project.update_attributes(params[:project])
    # saved
  else
    # not saved
  end
end
```

Comment: What library are you using for authentication? It looks like you are calling #readonly somewhere on your object - try a project-wide search for that.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It turns out it was related to using scopes to impersonate active record associations. I was able to fix it by adding `.readonly(false)` to my scopes.

Comment: I had the same problem, and this fixed it for me too. Any ideas what causes the `ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord` issue?

Comment: usually its an AR join that causes it, is "projects" a vanilla has_many on users or does it use a join clause?

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is create new file config/active_record_monkey_patch.rb and add following content in it.

```
module ReadOnlyFalse
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      def readonly?
        false
      end
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ReadOnlyFalse)
```

above code work for all models readonly(false).